# Waiting for thread to complete OkHttp Call

Tags: android, api, kotlin, okhttp

I have been having problems with [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) when I nest an OkHttp call inside another OkHttp call I am having a problem with the concurrency. I want to wait for my inner call to finish its thread's job before proceeding. Please take a look.

**Note: I am a novice with Kotlin and Multi-thread handling.**

```
   private fun parseJson(url: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
           .url(url)
           .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response?) {
            var bodyOfProducts = response?.body()?.string()

            var collectionJsonObject = jsonParseTool.fromJson(bodyOfProducts, Products::class.java)

            val productsWithDetails = ArrayList<ProductDetails>()


               for(product in collectionJsonObject.collects){
                   var concatProductUrl = "https://shopicruit.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?ids=" + product.product_id+ "&page=1&access_token=c32313df0d0ef512ca64d5b336a0d7c6"

                   val newRequest = Request.Builder()
                       .url(concatProductUrl)
                       .build()

                   val job = thread {
                       client.newCall(newRequest).enqueue(object : Callback {
                           override fun onResponse(call: Call, newResponse: Response?) {
                               var bodyOfProductDetails = newResponse?.body()?.string()
                               var productJsonObject = jsonParseTool.fromJson(bodyOfProductDetails, ProductDetails::class.java)
                               productsWithDetails.add(productJsonObject)
                           }

                           override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                               println("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE")
                           }
                       })
                   }
                   job.start()
                   job.join()  // This should force my thread to finish before the rest of the code is executed on the main thread.
               }



           // println(collectionJsonObject.collects[0].product_id)

            /*runOnUiThread {
                recyclerViewCustomCollections.adapter = CollectionsAdapter(jsonObject)
            }*/

        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Use execute instead of enqueue to make sure that it will be handled in 1 thread

Comment: @ HendraWD I tried what you said. The inner nested call is set to execute. When I run through debugger my thread is skipped and once the **for loop** is done, then the threads start to execute.                                                                                  
         var newResponse = client.newCall(newRequest).execute()

         var bodyOfProductDetails = newResponse?.body()?.string()

Comment: @HendraWD your right. That was the solution. When I ran in debugger since I could only target one thread at a time I was unable to see my interior code run when in fact the code was running. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should be using execute as mentioned and since http calls are handled asynchronously your thread is redundant and should be removed.

If you want to run code after all the requests are finished one way of doing this is by passing in a onComplete callback function and count the number of requests completed, when all of the threads are completed call the callback function containing the code that should be run after all of the requests.